# How to load sub report in Crystal Report in Asp.Net C# with out asking Parameter fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, subreport, subreports

I am developing software in asp.net c#, in that it have a Crystal Reports & also Crystal Reports has a sub report in it..

I load only main report through pass the value of bolReports.Year,

The problem is: I can't load sub report using the same parameter..

When I run the page means it ask parameter to sub reports..

Anyone help, thanks in advance..

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("tbl");
ReportDocument cryRptDoc = new ReportDocument();
string ReportPath = string.Empty;

bolReports.Year = ddlYear.SelectedValue.Trim();

ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~\\Reports\\PerCallBrnMon.rpt");
cryRptDoc.Load(ReportPath);
cryRptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(bolReports.UserID, bolReports.Password, bolReports.ServerName, bolReports.DataBaseName);
ds = bolReports.sp_CallClosing();
cryRptDoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRptDoc;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
CrystalReportViewer1.HasExportButton = false;
CrystalReportViewer1.HasPrintButton = false;
CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(80);
```

**Main Report Name :** PerCallBrnMon.rpt

**Sub Report Name :** PerCallBrnMonGrp.rpt

Error :

[image]

**Watch this..**

[image]

In this code, I have run only main report & main report stored procedure, & I don't know how to run sub report & sub report stored procedure.. the main report has a sub report in it, & both having the same parameter of `bolReports.Year`..

Answer (score 0):

In the template add the links between the main report and the subreport. It should be available in one of the options in the context menu of the subreport.

Comment: hi owczarek, the main report has sub report in report footer, both reports has same parameter.. & both reports has a different store procedure, i am used only one store procedure, but how to run subreport store procedure parallelly,  can u please explain briefly..

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never tried to steer the procedures execution in the report, always letting the crystal reports engine to do it. 
Also I do not understand how many procedures there are: are there two separate: one in the main and the second in the subreport (you've written 'both reports has a different store procedure') , or just one ('i am used only one store procedure')? If there are two, why you use just one? Are those procedures linked in the template? If yes, the CR mechanism should call them automatically.